# Vectorizing For Loop for Hilbert Matrix

Tags: python

A Hilbert matrix is a matrix whose elements are given by: a<sub>ij</sub> = (i+j-1)<sup>-1</sup>

How can I reduce the number of for loops to one in my below code via vectorizing part of the code.

```
def Hilbert(n):
    H = [[0]*n]*n
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            H[i][j] = 1/(i+j+1)
    return H
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code provided in the question does not work correctly, since it repeatedly overwrites the same list, so that in the end all rows of the resulting matrix are the same. One way to fix it and vectorize it is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def Hilbert(n):
    i, j = np.ogrid[1:n+1, 1:n+1]
    return 1/(i + j - 1)
```